# Adding content after "hero" section

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I have placed a fullscreen background video and some intro text into one section of a home page. Now I want to continue adding content to lower part of the homepage but something is totally messed up. You can see what I mean here:

[image]

I've made a red circle around the new content which I want to add as a new section below the video. For some reason it's stuck at the top of the page.

This is how the HTML looks like:

```
 <section id="fullscreen-bg">
        <video loop muted autoplay poster="img/landing_bg.jpg" class="fullscreen-bg__video">
            <source src="video/big_buck_bunny.webm" type="video/webm">
            <source src="img/demo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="video/big_buck_bunny.ogv" type="video/ogg">
        </video>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h1>dolm it</h1>
                    <p>Dolm IT is modern design & development agency from Estonia with main focus on complex web systems. We have a really kickass team whose main focus is UI/UX, PHP, Java, AngularJS, HTML & CSS.</p>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default white">more</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--end container-->
    </section>
    <!--end fullscreen-bg-->


    <section id="whatwedo">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">

                    <h1>what we do</h1>
                    <p>We offer a wide range of software development and design options from a simple web development to more complicated information systems. We ensure our customers get the right thing, done the right way.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
                   /*fullscreen bg*/

                    #fullscreen-bg h1 {
                        color: #ffffff;
                        font-family: 'Akrobat-ExtraBold';
                        font-size: 4.9rem;
                        text-transform: uppercase;
                        letter-spacing: 2px;
                        margin-bottom: 32px;
                    }

                    #fullscreen-bg p {
                        color: #ffffff;
                        font-family: 'Akrobat-Bold';
                        font-size: 1.5rem;
                    }

                    #fullscreen-bg .col-md-6 {
                        margin-top: 200px;
                        padding: 130px 0 130px 0;
                        display: -webkit-box;
                        display: -ms-flexbox;
                        display: flex;
                        -webkit-box-align: flex-start;
                        -ms-flex-align: flex-start;
                        align-items: flex-start;
                        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
                        -webkit-box-direction: reverse;
                        -ms-flex-direction: column;
                        flex-direction: column;
                        z-index: 10;
                    }
                    /*video bg*/

                    #fullscreen-bg {
                        position: fixed;
                        top: 0;
                        right: 0;
                        bottom: 0;
                        left: 0;
                        overflow: hidden;
                        z-index: -100;
                    }

                    .fullscreen-bg__video {
                        position: absolute;
                        top: 0;
                        left: 0;
                        width: 100%;
                        height: 100%;
                    }

                    #fullscreen-bg:before {
                        content: '';
                        background: rgba(14, 124, 132, 0.8);
                        width: 100%;
                        height: 100%;
                        position: absolute;
                        left: 0;
                        top: 0;
                        z-index: 1;
                    }

                    @media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
                        .fullscreen-bg__video {
                            width: 100%;
                            height: auto;
                        }
                    }

                    @media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
                        .fullscreen-bg__video {
                            width: auto;
                            height: 100%;
                        }
                    }

                    @media (max-width: 767px) {
                        #fullscreen-bg {
                            url(../img/landing_bg.jpg) no-repeat 0 30% fixed;
                        }
                        .fullscreen-bg__video {
                            display: none;
                        }
                    }
```

You can see the demo page [here](http://dolm.ragne.me/). Please help me with this issue so I can continue building this website. Thank you.

EDIT: This is how it should look like:

[image]

Comment: If only there was a design & development agency with main focus on complex web systems available to help ..

Comment: Your background is fixed position, so the block element you've added is placed at the top of the page since it doesn't interact with the fixed element. This is relatively basic CSS.

Comment: I've edited the original post to show what I want to achieve. It might be fundamental and basic but I'm totally new to HTML/CSS and that's why I'm asking for help in order to learn it all. :)

Comment: Okay, apologies for my overly sarcastic response. I would suggest not using a fixed element if you want it to be part of the page structure, perhaps a `display: block;` with `width: 100%; height: 100vh;` might be a good place to start.

Comment: Ok, I tried that now. It places the text at the bottom of the page, but it's still  part of the blue section. @DBS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to achieve can be done by setting the fullscreen section class as follows:

```
#fullscreen-bg {
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -100;
}
```

as shown above, the fullscreen-bg section should not be fixed position as it will always take the whole view of the browser and anyother content added will always be shown behind it.

Now to achieve the look you want remove the height: auto from the fullscreen-bg__video class in the media query for min-aspect-ratio: 16/9.

```
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9)
.fullscreen-bg__video {
width: 100%;
}
```

I think this will do what are looking for.

Hope this helps.

[Edit]

Please add margin-top:100px (or whatever suits) to the fullscreen-bg section to compensate for the navbar which is fixed on top. This will fix the what we do section margin issue of getting behind the first section when height of screen is bigger.

To cover the video white areas on the side add the following css

```
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9)
.fullscreen-bg__video {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1.2);
    -moz-transform: scaleX(1.2);
    -ms-transform: scaleX(1.2);
}
```

Just as for information: The best approach of setting the top margin of whatwedo section is to use jQuery on document.ready and window.resize methods by adding the navbar height + fullscreen-bg section height and setting that value as top margin for the whatwedo section. This will make it fully responsive and adjust itself based on the screen size.

Comment: Have updated the answer above. Please check and let me know if need more help.

Comment: Thank you so much, I think we're almost there. :) I made changes like you suggested and it looks almost perfect. If you don't mind, maybe you can take a look at this demo page link which I provided in my original post. The "What we do" heading still sits inside the video frame a bit. Should I just add some margin to it so it moves down? Would this be the correct way of doing it? @Nasir T

Comment: I now noticed that the video bg has a white bars on both sides. How should I remove these? @Nasir T

Comment: I have added more to the answer. See the [Edit] section in it for the text under the video issue. Also please vote or mark this as answer if this helped you. Thanks.

Comment: Added the solution to the white sides of video as well.  Please mark the answer or vote if this helped. Thanks and happy coding.

Comment: I made those changes but I see some issues there. First of all the website's got a horizontal scrollbar for some reason. Next, the intro text on the video has moved down a bit, it was centered before. And things start going weird when I resize the window to smaller viewports. At some point those bars appear again, then disappear and the intro text moves downward more. You have been really helpul and I'd appreciate it if you could help me some more. If you don't mind and if it doesn't take too much time. :) @Nasir T

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126363/discussion-between-nasir-t-and-bijoume).